# how to search in a file and read lines from there in python

Tags: python, regex, string, file

I have a huge text file about 100000 lines, that I want to read. I am not interested in all the contents. I want to search for the line that starts with "Residue XXX "
and read the next three lines from there.
I dont want to read the entire lines in a list in buffer. Is there an efficient way to search for this line and read from there on

```
f=open("result.txt",r)
lines = f.readlines()// NOT preferred
```

I just want some input if there is a way to search for this line in entire file instead of reading them and iterating over.

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: well, I want some input to try..

Comment: You could of course run `grep -A 3 '^Residue XXX' result.txt` and work with the output of that command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open("result.txt") as f:
   # find line starting with Residue XXX
   next(line for line in f if not line.startswith("Residue XXX"))
   # get next three lines into a list (empty string for nonexistent lines)
   results = [next(f, "").rstrip() for line in range(3)]
```

If you want to keep the `Residue XXX` line as the first item of the `results` list:

```
with open("result.txt") as f:
   # find line starting with Residue XXX
   results = [next(line for line in f if not line.startswith("Residue XXX").rstrip()]
   # add next three lines to the list (empty string for nonexistent lines)
   results.extend(next(f, "").rstrip() for line in range(3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like:

```
read_lines = None

for l in open("result.txt"):
    if read_lines:
        print l.encode('unicode_escape')
        read_lines -= 1
    if read_lines == 0: 
        break
    if l.startswith('Residue ddG RotamerProbability'):
        read_lines = 3
```

there are subtlier solutions, but this is straightforward and simple.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any way to search in a file other than by reading the data. There are more or less efficient ways to read the data, so for example doing it in C might be faster than a loop in Python, but presumably Python is what you want to use.

The `itertools` module provides two functions relating to what you want: `dropwhile` searches for a value with a particular property and `islice` selects a range of values from an iterable:

```
import itertools

with open('result.txt') as infile:
    def predicate(line):
        return not line.startswith('Residue XXX')
    result = list(itertools.islice(itertools.dropwhile(predicate, infile), 1, 4))

print result
```

Answer (score 0):

A file object is an iterator and it will keep going if you use it in a different place. islice is a handy function to get items from an iterator. Putting it all together, use a for loop to find the starting position and islice to get the rest.

I'm not sure whether you wanted to include the matched line in your list or what you wanted to do with line endings, so I decided to add the matched line plus the next 3 lines, without the trailing line feed.

```
from itertools import islice
with open('result.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("Residue XXX"):
           my_list = [line.strip()]
           my_list.extend(extra.strip() for extra in islice(f, 3))
           break
```